# Is it possible to dd a file from within a VM to a physical disk on the host?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtual-machine, external-hard-drive, dd

I'm trying to clone a physical external hard drive from drive A to B. Drives A and B are both 2TB large. I have a host Windows 10 PC with a Linux VM.

I am first cloning from drive A (which shows up as /dev/sdb on the Linux VM, into an image file on the VMware shared folder on the host drive, using dd.

Next, I wish to dd the image file onto a drive B, which is a physical disk connected to the host SATA port, so it doesn't show use in the /dev file system. Shared folders won't work since drive B is unpartitioned. Short of connecting drive B as an external USB drive, is there any way to access it from the Linux VM to dd the image file to it?

Comment: You are aware that `dd` will copy empty space as well?  I would recommend using a disk dump/clone tool like `clonezilla` instead of `dd`.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this. This is exactly my intent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not running dd from a running Linux VM:-

You could boot a live Linux distro from DVD or USB.
This would enable you to mount your VMware shared folder and dd the image file  to drive B.

Those two dd's are going to be rather slow and you will need to take great care in identifying drive B.

Comment: I'm running dd from a live running vm. Is it possible this way without rebooting the host?

Comment: The first dd will create an image of the VM's disk whilst it is active, and this **could** be in a rather indeterminate state. It might work, but I wouldn't be surprised if when you boot machine B that your filesystems need fsck'ing.
This is why I suggested using a live distro to do your second dd, as this would not mount your filesystems.
Worth a try - possibily...

Comment: Drive A isn't mounted nor active. It's simply connected via USB.

Comment: Since dd x 2 is going to be super slow, I'd suggest you set up a VM that uses minimal space. Then try the double dd on this. Check the drive B works as it should. Then you would be in a position to do the long-running dd's on 2TB.

Comment: Just a thought - if your VM disk is mostly empty, then you could pipe the dd output through a compression program to get your 1st output and decompress this via dd onto your drive B. Could speed things up hugely with moderate CPU resources...